# Passport + Express V4 req.user undefined

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, passport.js

I use the module passport to create authentication with session .. But since express v4 , there is no more tutorial .. and my authentication doesn't work , in effect in my function that verify if the user is authenticated , the req.user is always undefined and req.isAuthenticated is false !

```
exports.ensureAuthenticated = function(req, res, next) {    
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) { return next(); }
  res.redirect('/login');
}

app.use(connect.logger('dev')); 
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(connect.cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser());
app.use(connect.cookieSession({ secret: 'keyboard cat', cookie: { secure: true }})); 
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

Any solution ?

Answer (score 7):

Passport works with Express 4 just fine.
I had the same problem when trying to user Angularjs, turns out the user wasn't logging in the first place.
Are your `passport.serializeUser` and `passport.deserializeUser` functions being called?
If that's the case, are you using custom callbacks?
When following a tutorial that did not user Angularjs I had to use a custom callback:

```
    router.post('/login', function (req, res, next) {
        passport.authenticate('local-login',  function (err, user, info) {
            if (err) {
                return next(err); // will generate a 500 error
            }
            if (!user) {
                return res.send({ success : false, message : info.message || 'Falha no login' });
            }

            req.logIn(user, function(err) {
                if (err) { return next(err); }
                return res.send({ success : true, message : 'Login efetivado com sucesso', user: user });
            });

            //return res.send({ success : true, message : 'Login efetivado com sucesso', user: user });
        })(req, res, next);
    });
```

I was not calling `req.logIn`, so the user was never serialized/deserialized and `req.isAuthenticated()` was always false.

Comment: I feel that after doing the custom callback I'm at least gaining more insight into my issue. I see that req.isAuthenticated() returns true in the req.logIn callback and I'm getting my success message in the response. Unfortunately for me subsequent calls still do not show as authenticated and the deserializeUser is not called.

Answer (score 5):

If you have cookie.secure set to true and you're NOT using SSL (i.e. https protocol) then the cookie with the session id is not returned to the browser and everything fails silently. Removing this flag resolved the problem for me.

```
app.use(session({ 
    secret: 'something', 
    cookie: { 
        secure: true
}}));
```